# Callback after image attr.src is done

Tags: jquery

Here is my function

```
var img = new Image();

$(img).load(function () {

    $(this).css('display','none');

    $(el).removeClass('loading').append(this);

    $(this).fadeIn();

}).error(function () {
    $(el).remove();
}).attr('src', srcImage);
```

I need to get the width of the loaded image or `srcImage`

I can do this with

```
var w = $('.parent_element').find('img').css('width');
```

but it needs to be done after `srcImage` is completely loaded

Comment: Just adding the line to the callback should work.

Comment: @FelixKling the thing is , there is no callback !

Comment: I think he meant inside the load() callback

Comment: @max You are wrong! Look on my answer and read source.

Comment: @max: What's the thing you are passing to the `.load` function? Looks like a callback to me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery images Loaded plugin

```
//Initially hide the image with CSS
visibility: hidden

//container holding your images
$('.photos').imagesLoaded(function () {
    //Function to measure size

    //Take measurements
    var w = $('img').width();
    var h = $('img').height();

    //Once you know the proper size, show it
    $('img').show();              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try something that.

From jQuery:

**Example: Add the class bigImg to all images with height greater then 100 upon each image load.**

```
$('img.userIcon').load(function(){
    if($(this).height() > 100) {
        $(this).addClass('bigImg');
    }
});
```

### [Source](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)